# AWS lambda invalid imageSyncing error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am setting up AWS Lambda. Adding is successful. While testing I am getting this error. I am this as a sample:

http://jice.lavocat.name/blog/2015/image-conversion-using-amazon-lambda-and-s3-in-node.js/

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/imageSyncing'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
     "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
     "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
     "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not created your deployment package correctly. I suspect you zipped the directory of your project instead of the *contents* of the directory.

Your zip file should only contain the `js` files and `node_modules` and not the directory where you placed them in.

Reference: [Creating a Deployment Package (Node.js)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)